# SharePoint 2010 HTML Editor to use P not Div

Tags: publishing, html-editor

Does anyone know of a way to make the default SharePoint 2010 HTML editor output a P tag when you hit enter, as opposed to a Div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line after typing but before hitting enter, select the text and on the ribbon goto Markup Styles > Paragraph.  After that is will create a new paragraph for each line break.

Comment: There is no way to change the default behavior other than that.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a go. It's a shame you can't configure it as this approach is not intuitive at all. There's little chance of end-user editors remembering to do this.

Comment: A lot of my end users just hit enter twice to make their line breaks. Not the cleanest HTML code generated but they don't know the difference.